# Need an example on how to use the ExecuteReader with a ParamArray

Tags: vb.net, parameters, parameter-passing, executereader

Can somebody please provide an example of how to use the ExecuteReader calling a stored procedure with a parameter array?

Comment: "Parameter array"? Do you mean the Parameters collection on the [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)?

Comment: Not sure if that's what I'm asking. The overload calls it a ParamArray of parameterValues declared as Object. I'm trying the parameters collection of the SQLCommand right now but getting an exception. So it may not be that.

Comment: And maybe I should specify that I'm trying to use the Enterprise Library ExecuteReader.

Comment: and I think I just solved my own problem. I was searching for ExecuteReader examples but should search for IDataReader

Comment: Actually, IDataReader is an interface used by (for example) SqlDataReader, the object returned when running ExecuteReader from SqlCommand. It's "higher" in the chain and, while it may provide some tools to access your data, you'd be better off using the SqlDataReader methods (i.e. ExecuteReader) if you're accessing your data via a SqlCommand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site with an example:

http://forums.asp.net/t/387752.aspx/1?ExecuteReader+for+stored+procedure+with+2+input+parameters+not+working

If you are looking to just loop through the array of parameters, this code will work:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308049

Comment: Thank you for the example. I realize now I was asking for the wrong thing but than you anyway. Your suggestions got me on the right track (should be searching for iDataReader and not ExecuteReader)